# android studio does not start, dies with stack trace, how to find what is causing this

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to learn/write flutter apps and android studio keeps blowing up on start up.  Below are the first couple of errors that android studio prints when it starts and next is the error that pops up in the popup that android studio displays with an ok button.  this is repeatable and happens across multiple versions after reinstalling on my laptop.  Using this guide I tried to delete anything that could be causing the problem as well, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-windows/ , and it is not working.  Java is spitting out ovw 2000 lines of errors messages and stack traces, this is confusing.  I looked at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues for help and I did not find anything that helped. Thanks for the help

- OS: windows 10
- Android Studio: 2022.3.1.18
- Android studio JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)

```
bin $ .\studio.bat
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
2023-08-14 12:02:31,575 [   6419]   WARN - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - `include` is supported only on a root level ([row,col,system-id]: [176,5,"C:\Users\ms472\scoop\apps\android-studio\2022.3.1.18\plugins\Kotlin\lib\kotlin-idea.jar"])
2023-08-14 12:02:32,374 [   7218] SEVERE - #c.i.i.ApplicationLoader - Receiver class com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidPluginInitializer does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void beforeApplicationLoaded(com.intellij.openapi.application.Application, java.nio.file.Path)' of interface com.intellij.ide.ApplicationLoadListener.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.android.tools.idea.startup.AndroidPluginInitializer does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void beforeApplicationLoaded(com.intellij.openapi.application.Application, java.nio.file.Path)' of interface com.intellij.ide.ApplicationLoadListener.
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.initConfigurationStore(ApplicationLoader.kt:387)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$doInitApplication$4.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:85)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
2023-08-14 12:02:32,396 [   7240] SEVERE - #c.i.i.ApplicationLoader - Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1  Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996
2023-08-14 12:02:32,396 [   7240] SEVERE - #c.i.i.ApplicationLoader - JDK: 17.0.6; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-08-14 12:02:32,402 [   7246] SEVERE - #c.i.i.ApplicationLoader - OS: Windows 10
2023-08-14 12:02:32,455 [   7299] SEVERE - #c.i.i.ApplicationLoader - com/intellij/configurationStore/StateStorageManager$DefaultImpls
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/configurationStore/StateStorageManager$DefaultImpls
        at org.jetbrains.settingsRepository.IcsManager.beforeApplicationLoaded(IcsManager.kt:145)
        at org.jetbrains.settingsRepository.IcsApplicationLoadListener.beforeApplicationLoaded(IcsManager.kt:259)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.initConfigurationStore(ApplicationLoader.kt:387)
        at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$doInitApplication$4.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:85)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

from the popup android studio displays:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: call to AndroidStudioAnalytics before initialization
    at com.intellij.analytics.AndroidStudioAnalytics.getInstance(AndroidStudioAnalytics.java:38)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.isAllowed(UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.java:137)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.utils.StatisticsUploadAssistant.isSendAllowed(StatisticsUploadAssistant.java:34)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.AndroidStudioStatisticsJobScheduler.componentsInitialized(AndroidStudioStatisticsJobScheduler.kt:38)
    at com.intellij.ide.ApplicationInitializedListener.execute$suspendImpl(ApplicationInitializedListener.kt:21)
    at com.intellij.ide.ApplicationInitializedListener.execute(ApplicationInitializedListener.kt)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$callAppInitialized$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationLoader.kt:436)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Users\[REDACTED]\scoop\apps\android-studio\2022.3.1.18\jbr
```

Comment: do you have any solution for this? I have the same error on Linux.

Comment: UPDATE: Very strange, I changed the installation from my SSD to my HDD and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Linux and finally deleted the entire Android Studio folder and reinstalled. I had updated into the previous folder and so suspect some old files were still in place causing issues. So a fresh install after deleting all past files worked for me.